# How to define JSON with Lombok in properties: @JsonPropertyOrder and @JsonIgnore (JAVA)

Tags: java, json, lombok

I'm trying to use lombok with JSON but I have some hiccups

> Json is not respecting the order when the name of the variable is
>   different from @JsonProperty.

(it's probably a problem with the getters)

> Another point is that I would like to hide the id of the Object1 in
>   the generated json

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "objectid", "value" })
public class Object1 {

@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

@JsonProperty("objectid")
private Long subid;

@JsonProperty("value")
private String value;

}
```

Result:

```
{
  "id" : 123,  <--- I want to hide
  "value" : "...",
  "objectid" : 123
}
```

"this is a small and fictional class"

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: First: Im not using the ObjectMapper, Second: if you see the resoult my "objectid" appears as last member and the "id" still there.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the output order try to use `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = om.writeValueAsString(myObject1);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

To hide the id you can use this jackson annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id"})
```

If you still want to be able to set the id using setter add this member to the annotation:

```
allowSetters = true
```

Comment: Which is the difference between @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id"}) and @JsonIgnore "in this case" ? because I know that one is at Class Level and the another at Value Level, but i dont see the difference in the result.

Comment: It's more or less the same, but as you're using lombok, if you want to allow setters for the id field, this is only available with @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine...
What do you want to get in result?
[image: Your code]

Comment: When i declare my public Response save(Object1 object1) { } in swagger appears the "id" and the "objectid" is the last member